# Excel VBA 1004 error occured when .usedrange.unmerge to Worksheets including Table

Tags: excel, vba

Sheet1 has Table data.
And I execute below code, Excel show me 1004 error.
Could you tell me why Excel show error? is root cause unmerge functionality?

```
Sub TETS()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ws.UsedRange.UnMerge

End Sub
```

when delete table from Sheet1, error was not shown.
but I want to apply unmerge to all Worksheets, such like including table data.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `UnMerge` you can use `MergeCells = False`:

```
ws.UsedRange.MergeCells = False
```

Comment: Didn't know that. I will delete my answer as this is obviously much easier.